# React Komposer, react and Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Im Using react Komposer meteor and react .
I have this component

```
import React from 'react';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import lightBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

const lightMuiTheme = getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme);

const Questiondetails = ({ thequestion }) => (
  <div>
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={lightMuiTheme}>
      <h4>{thequestion.header}</h4>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </div>
);


export default Questiondetails;
```

And this is the container

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import CircularProgress from 'material-ui/CircularProgress';
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import Questiondetails from '../../../ui/components/Questiondetails/Questiondetails.jsx';
import Questions from '../../Collections/Questions/Questions.js';

function composer(props, onData) {
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('singleQuestion', props._id);

  if (handle.ready()) {
    const thequestion = Questions.findOne({ id: props._id });
    onData(null, { thequestion });
  }
}

const darkMuiTheme = getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme);

const MyLoading = () => (<div style={{ width: '90%', position: 'relative'   }}>
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={darkMuiTheme}>
    <div style={{ margin: 'auto', right: 0, left: 0, maxWidth: 200, position: 'relative' }}>
      <CircularProgress size={1.0} />
    </div>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
</div>);

export { MyLoading };

export default composeWithTracker(composer, MyLoading)(Questiondetails);
```

Im getting `Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined`
What could I be doing. 
When I look over at meteor toys. I get to see the subscription in the component.

This is my publication

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

// import the db
import Questions from '../../../../api/Collections/Questions/Questions.js';

// the publish
Meteor.publish('singleQuestion', function(id){
  return Questions.find({ _id: id });
});
```

Comment: You need to conditionally call `onData` (only if `thequestion` is not `undefined`)

Comment: How do I do that. Please show in a code example

Comment: Just to make sure, can you post your `singleQuestion` publication?

Comment: Ive updated the question with the publication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that you don't get the data record.

Even after the subscription `handle` is ready, it is possible that the query returns `undefined`, either because there is no data in the collection or if your query is wrong.

In this case, it seems that the query is indeed wrong, leading to you passing `undefined` to the component instead of the expected object.

If you provide a string as the first argument to `find()` or `findOne()`, it is assumed that you mean the `_id`, so it prevents errors like the (common) one you made (`Questions.findOne({ id: props._id })`, using the `id` key instead of `_id`).

You can use the `error` argument in order to catch such cases more easily (and show a meaningful error message in case something is actually wrong).

I also suggest changing `thequestion` to simply be `question` or `theQuestion` (more readable), unless there is a very good reason not to.

```
function composer(props, onData) {
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('singleQuestion', props._id);

  if (handle.ready()) {
    const question = Questions.findOne(props._id);
    let error = null;
    if (!question) {
      error = new Error('no question matches the provided id');
    }
    onData(error, {question});
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked. I got the data to show up without any errors in the console